# How to create the custom plugins in iOS

Tags: cordova, ios6

How to Create Custom Plugins in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) to learn how to develop a **custom plugin for iOS**.
I recommend also to take a look at the [existing plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins).

Comment: thanks a lot.., Actualy, I have so many objective C files i need to acces these files through plugin.. How to cal these methods